# How to position this empty movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have two images pulling though an empty movie clip, using the actionscript below. I can't seem to figure out how to position both of them, could anybody shed some light on this? I'm using AS3.

Thanks for any help. Philip

```
    var mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    var list:Object = new Object();
    mcl.addListener(list);

    var myMovies:Array = new Array(tbSKUImage.text, tbSKUImage2.text);
    var cont:Number = 0;

    function loadSwfs(){
    createEmptyMovieClip("target"+cont, getNextHighestDepth());
    eval("target"+cont)._x = eval("target"+(cont-1))._x + eval("target"+(cont-                      1))._width + 60;
 mcl.loadClip(myMovies[cont], eval("target"+cont));
 }

    list.onLoadInit = function(){
    if(cont < myMovies.length){
    cont++;
    loadSwfs();
    }
    else{
    trace("Load complete");
    }}

    loadSwfs();
```

Comment: You say "I'm using AS3" but the code is AS2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use eval().  It has been deprecated since Flash 5, and it is known to behave strangely.  Instead, use object notation:

```
this["target"+cont]
```

or simply assign a reference to the empty clip to a local variable, and keep a member variable with the x position:

```
var xpos:Number = 0;

// other code

function loadSwfs(){
    var mc:MovieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("target"+cont, getNextHighestDepth());
    mc._x = xpos;
    xpos += mc._width + 60;
    mcl.loadClip(myMovies[cont], mc);
}
```